# pause() - waitUntil/waitForXXX behaviour

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

### The problem

Inconsistent (AFAIK) behaviour between `browser.pause()` and `waitUntil(...)`, `waitForExist` methods

### Environment

- WebdriverIO version: 4.6.2
- Node.js version: 6.9.4
- [Standalone mode or wdio testrunner](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/modes.html): testrunner
- if wdio testrunner, running synchronous or asynchronous tests: sync
- Additional wdio packages used (if applicable):

  - "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.1.2",
  - "wdio-json-reporter": "^0.2.1",
  - "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.8",
  - "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.8",
  - "wdio-spec-reporter": "0.0.5"

### Details

First snippet:

```js
browser.url(Navigation.BASE_URL + Navigation.PATH_URL)
browser.pause(waitFor * Navigation.MILLIS) // Recomended NOT use
bodyEl = $("html body");
/*
browser.waitUntil(function() {
    return $("div#navModule.navModule").state === 'success';
});
*/
// browser.waitForExist("div#navModule.navModule");
console.log('[Navigation::startup] style:' +
    JSON.stringify($("div#navModule.navModule").getCssProperty('display')));
```

Prints `[Navigation::startup] style:{"property":"display","value":"none","parsed":{"type":"ident","string":"none"}}`, which is **OK**

But, if I replace `browser.pause` for `browser.waitUntil` (or `waitForExist`), as recommended in docs, just like:

```js
browser.url(Navigation.BASE_URL + Navigation.PATH_URL)

// browser.pause(waitFor * Navigation.MILLIS) // Recomended NOT use
bodyEl = $("html body");
browser.waitUntil(function() {
    return $("div#navModule.navModule").state === 'success';
});
// browser.waitForExist("div#navModule.navModule");
console.log('[Navigation::startup] style:' +
    JSON.stringify($("div#navModule.navModule").getCssProperty('display')));
```

it prints `[Navigation::startup] style:{"property":"display","value":"block","parsed":{"type":"ident","string":"block"}}`, which is **wrong** as I know that element has attribute `style="display: none"` at this moment.

This is the very first step on running the suite.

So, what am I doing wrong?

thanks!!!

w

Comment: If your `style="display: none"` is inline it won't be returned by `.getCssProperty`. Instead use `.getAttribute("style")`.

Comment: @timothy-cope Mmmm, I'm not observing that behaviour right now. In fact, `getAttribute('style')` is returning nothing at all :-S. Things keep getting messy on using `waitForXXX` methods.